# Facebook post API Actions syntax

Tags: facebook, api, action

Is it possible to have more than one action in the JSON encoded Facebook post API action array, if so what is the correct syntax for two links? e.g. I want to have Link1 and Link2 >

```
'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Link1',
'link' => $Link1))
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it is not possible to have multiple action links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Facebook dropped it without saying anything about it in their docs like a year ago. You can put only one action link.